How to translate "only for those tho are responsible for themselves" into Latin
I want to translate the phrase "only for those tho are responsible for themselves" to Latin as a motto of my group but I'm not sure how to translate it in a concise way.
I guess I should use "... solum" in Latin for " only for ..." in English, "sibi" for "forthemselves", but it's still difficult for me to translate the clause...

There is a handy expression: in tutelam suam venire (or as L&S notes more commonly in this order: suam tutelam). It literally means to come under one's own guardianship, i.e., to be responsible for oneself. - that is, to be mature.
Assuming that this is the responsibility you were looking for, there are two main ways to formulate this for: either with a dative or with "ad + accusative". Thus we can write:
Ad eos qui in suam tutelam (per)venerunt or more succinctly Ad venientes .... But this later option translates in the present tense.
Lastly, I think solum is a fine choice, but one might consider also tantum.
